# Binary representation of a string

Tags: haskell

Assuming I have some ASCII characters in a string, let's say `s = "ABC"`, how can I retrieve the binary/bit representation as a string?

In this case,

```
A = 41 = "01000001"
B = 42 = "01000010"
C = 43 = "01000011"
```

so I want something like `make_binary "ABC"` to return `"010000010100001001000011"`

I don't know if there's any way to get the encoded value of a character, and (if there is) I don't know if there's any way to get the 'bit-representation' of that value.

I could solve this with a straight map from character to 'bit-representation string' but hope there's a better approach.

Comment: Hoogle the functions. [`ord :: Char -> Int`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=ord+%3A%3A+Char+-%3E+Int&scope=set%3Astackage). As for converting to binary, I'm sure you could easily write a little recursive function for that, it's not hard.

Comment: The `make_binary` function you are asking for needs to take both a string AND an encoding. You cannot write such a function without an encoding, unless you are assuming UTF-8 everywhere, which I guess is fine. So just to be clear, you DO want UTF-8, correct?

Comment: @RayToal yes. thanks for the clarification. I assume everything is UTF-8 but it's useful to call that out.

Comment: @AJFarmar Hoogle is great and useful, but for a simple type signature like `Char -> Int` I get a ton of hits, each with pretty concise and pithy documentation or comment.

Comment: `Char` is not (user-visibly) UTF-8 encoded; it is a Unicode codepoint. If you want a specific encoding, you must encode first to a suitable type (`ByteString` is a popular choice for that).

Comment: The question says 'ASCII' - I'm only interested in simple English characters [a-zA-Z] in ASCII/UTF-8. I can improve the question if people give feedback - I don't see why it deserves 3 downvotes.

Comment: Yes UTF-32 is the easiest thing to do here. I'm sure someone has solved the problem of turning a Haskell String into bytes with UTF-8, then you just have to map the to-8-bit-binary-string over each byte.

Comment: Oh sorry I missed the ASCII part.... I guess I was not expecting it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I downvoted because the question is very basic and easily answerable by just browsing the standard libraries for a little while. So a priori it looks like you haven't done your due diligence before asking.

Answer (score 5):

You can get where you need to go with `fromEnum` (or its specialized version `ord`) and `showIntAtBase`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick ASCII-only version that might help:

```
Prelude Data.Char Text.Printf Data.List> format = Text.Printf.printf::String->Int->String
Prelude Data.Char Text.Printf Data.List> intercalate "" $ map (format "%08b" . ord) "ABCD"
"01000001010000100100001101000100"
```

Comment: Is `intercalate ""`  just `concat`?

Comment: Yep, for `List Char` they are the same. Good eye, that would have been cleaner. :)